# GIT - SSIS DB Production Server not in sync (Deployment without Commit)

Tags: sql-server, git, ssis

I've started a new job as a BI Dev working with SQL Server, and I've run across a major issue that was left behind by old lazy devs.

Without any controls or deployment models implemented, there's been a free for all on deployment to the production server. As a result there is a discrepancy between the SSIS packages that are on the SSIS Catalog on the production server and what is in source control.

Does anyone know a method that I can use to grab all of the SSIS projects deployed to the server and sync them into git?

Comment: You can't sync from SSISDB to git, no. I would suggest downloading the project(s) from SSISDB, and then putting the files that need updating (updated or missing `dtsx` files and the project file) into your source controlled directory. Then you can commit from there.

Comment: won't sync to git, but I've used the export powershell scripts here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ImportExport-projects-bca5f29f  It will download all the projects into ispac files.   Update the connection string to your ssis server.  ispac are just compressed files, I added a small adjustment to those scripts and had it also extract all the files from the ispac into each of the project folders.  That might get you part way there.